# How can I get the RTSP URL for Youtube to be play on videoview

Tags: android, youtube, android-videoview

Hi i want to get a url from youtube to be play on my videoview. I tried putting the whole url from youtube but it always prompt "Can't play this video". I also tried using http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ + the video ID but still not working.. Can anybody help me? Please thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to play Youtube video, Youtube app should be installed on your device.

Why don't you use YoutubePlayer instead?

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

------------------------- Edit ---------------------------------

I forgot to mention it. To use YoutubePlayer library, you must get DEVELOPER_KEY.

```
youTubeView.initialize('DEV_KEY' , YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener);
```

This link might be helpful : http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android-app/

Comment: is there any other way to do it? instead of installing youtube app?

Comment: i tried using it but i always have an error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.initialize(java.lang.String, com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer$OnInitializedListener)' on a null object reference @Daniel